# Does ethers.js works with quorum?

Tags: web3js

I understand that ethers.js is an alternative to web3js.

I have used web3js with ethers.js with quorum. Does anyone used ether.js with quorum before?

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried on quorum yet. I'm using it with go-ethereum clique, which is the proof-of-authority implementation of ethereum (private network).

A quick look around shows me that they have a slightly modificated web3 api (web3j-quorum and https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/blob/master/docs/api.md )

ethersjs or standard web3 would of course not work for the extra features quorum offers like constellation.

You can likely still connect ethersjs clients to a JSON-RPC on a node to send normal transactions.

```
const ethers = require('ethers')
const Providers = ethers.providers

const node1= "http://127.0.0.1:8501"
const node2= "http://127.0.0.1:8502"
const provider1 = new Providers.JsonRpcProvider(node1, 'clique')
const provider2 = new Providers.JsonRpcProvider(node2, 'clique')
const fallbackProvider = new Providers.FallbackProvider([provider1, provider2])
```

This sets up a RPC connection to a node, with a fallback to another node.
You can then initiate a wallet through one of the methods and bind fallbackProvider to wallet.provider

I did add my network to networks.json in the source code though.
ethers>providers>networks.json

```
"clique": {
  "chainId": 999,
  "name": "clique"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a third party library **ethers-quorum** [github](https://github.com/rodion-lim-partior/ethers-quorum) / [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethers-quorum) that allows for submission of private transactions.

Using ethers directly will only allow you read pure / view smart contract functions. Sending transactions require additional parameters to be passed in the json RPC calls, which needs a patch on top of existing libraries.